# Powershell pass parameter to sqlcmd

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

I'm trying to pass username, db and pwd as variable to `sqlcmd` - but it does not seem to like it.

This works

```
#Run SQLCMD for each file
ForEach ($FileName in $FileNames)
{
    Write-Host $FileName.BaseName
    sqlcmd -S 123.database.net -d EMR -U user1-P mypassword -i $FileName.FullName
}
```

This does not work

```
#Run SQLCMD for each file
$db = "123.database.net"
$dbId = "user1"
$pwd = "mypassword"

ForEach ($FileName in $FileNames)
{
    Write-Host $FileName.BaseName
    sqlcmd -S $db -d EMR -U $dbId -P $pwd -i $FileName.FullName
}
```

Error message

> sqlcmd : Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'user1'..

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What error message(s) do you get? Have you output the command line being executed to check that it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

sqlcmd has its scope .Make the variables as Global. Then it should pick it.

DO this:

```
#Run SQLCMD for each file
$global:db = "123.database.net"
$global:dbId = "user1"
$global:pwd = "mypassword"
ForEach ($FileName in $FileNames)
{

Write-Host $FileName.BaseName
sqlcmd -S $db -d EMR -U $dbId -P $pwd -i $FileName.FullName

}
```

Note: I have not taken into consideration that your second scriptlet is throwing any error in particular or not.

Comment: that did not help

Comment: @JustinHomes : Post the error. It would be very generic to give some solution without seeing the cause for it.

Comment: So as mentioned by you, its  login issue. Have you tried directly from the console. Because it states clearly login failed for user1. Means either the password issue or the permission issue for the user